Pivot Table average from all columns including blanks
I have a list of plant species observed at 10 individual sub-sites.  Each site may contain all or just some of the plant species so what happens is that in the pivot table, in one sub-site there is just a blank while others may contain a value.  The average for the 10 sites is correct if only including the sub-sites that contain a value, but I'd also like to include the non-numbered sub-sites into the calculation as well.  Going back through the data is arduous.  Any way of including non-values into the average?
Sample of Pivot Table

What value do you want them included as? Zero?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Each sub-site can have a variety of plants growing.  Some sub-sites may have plants growing in them that others don't.  So when doing a pivot table summary of all the plants in the 10 sub-sites and ones that didn't have a plant in that sub-site is left blank as in the attached picture.  So an answer to @music2myear is yes, they should be zeros, but as they were not entered in the raw data, it would be very arduous to go back in and list every possible plant across the 10 sub-sites and enter zeros where they weren't growing.

So as an example in the picture, the first row's average is 4 because on one sub-site had that plant growing in it, but in reality, the average is 0.4 because the other nine had 0 plants growing in it, but the pivot table average is only counting the one sub-site.

Why not use the SUM/10?

I think you can fill the corresponding blanks ​​with 0 in the source data.

How did you create the Average column in your Pivot Table?

Could you paste the source data screenshot
"I'd also like to include the non-numbered sub-sites into the calculation as well."
I presume we got to set blanks to 0 (zero), but I'm struggling to guess what the source data looks like

This is NOT an answer to the question and should be deleted. You can post it as a comment if you have enough reputation.
